# Why mongoose schema type is double, but when insert value, type in mongo is int32?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose-double to define Double type for mongoose.
My schema contain values property is an array of Double.

In pre-save middleware, init values is an array with 6 items 1000.
Check in mongo, 1000 type is int32

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);

const Double = mongoose.Schema.Types.Double;

const test = new mongoose.Schema({
   values: [Double]
})

test.pre('save', function(next) {
   this.values = new Array(6).fill(1000),
})
```

I did what wrong ?

Comment: Because Double is not a valid SchemaTypes in Mongoose. Check https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html for all the valid SchemaTypes in Mongoose.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc yes I know, but I used mongoose-double to support that.
If I input value = 1.1, it's okay with type = Double in mongo.
But when I input value = 1 or value =1.0, type = int32 in mongo. It's not match with my model

Comment: it worked fine for me. Try changing `values: [Double]` to `values: {type: [Double]}`

Comment: Still not working :(

Answer (score -1):

Well, in my opinion, you don't need to use Double.

As far as I know, there is 'Number' type in mongoose schema and it can be double, number and etc.

So use Number instead of Double.

```
const test = new mongoose.Schema({
   values:Number
})
```

but in your case, you should use like this.

```
const test = new mongoose.Schema({
   values:[Number]
})
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to the type of values is only double in mongo.
If use Number type, when I input value = 1, mongo type = int32, but I want type = Double